# Beckmann distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I know that if $r_x \sim \cal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $r_y \sim \cal{N}(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$, then the pdf of $r=\sqrt{r_x^2 + r_y^2}$ is given by:

$$ f_r(r) = \frac{r}{2 \pi \sigma_x \sigma_y} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}{ \exp\left(-\frac{(r cos(\phi)-\mu_x)^2}{2 \sigma_x^2} -\frac{(r sin(\phi)-\mu_y)^2}{2 \sigma_y^2}\right) d\phi}$$

I want to know if there is an approximation or a different expression for the Beckmann pdf $f_r(r)$. In fact, I want to get rid of the integral and have a nicer expression that I can manipulate easily later.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you know about the Rayleigh distribution. If not, I suggest you read about it, possibly starting with the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I know the Rayleigh distribution. It's a special case of the Beckmann distribution. I did not understand quite well your comment.